# How to close input='file' after drag-n-dropping elems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I have a react app with input="file".
After dragging elems from input to page, I want the input to close automatically.

I use useRef hook to trigger input oppenning by clicking on the button.

P.S I've tried a lot of different methods, like inputRef.current.value = ''. This method doesn't work.
Please help!